# Simple copy constructor in C++

Tags: c++, c++11, copy-constructor, deep-copy

Let's say we have two classes in C++:

```
Class A{
      public:
          A();
      private:
          int k;
};

Class B{
      public:
          B();
      private:
          A a;
};
```

*I edit my question such that it is more helpful for anyone does reach it someday.*

How could I write the copy ctor of `B` (is it a copy ctor indeed?) for initializing `a` (which is of type `Class A`) with another object instance of `A` (let it be `a_inst`) which have already been defined and initialized before?

In other words, what would be the code for the ctor B()?

Comment: you don't, in cases like yours it's simpler to just remove all constructors and let the [compiler generate them all for you](https://rmf.io/cxx11/rule-of-zero/).

Comment: You don't need a copy-constructor unless your class deals with a resource of some kind. In your case it doesn't so just let the compiler handle everything for you. Read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_(C%2B%2B_programming) for more info.

Comment: @bashrc gave the solution below. I edited my question such that it's more helpful. Thanks again!

Comment: @StillLearning that's a very helpful read, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it like this

```
B(const A &paramA) : a(paramA) {}
B(A &&paramA) : a(move(paramA)) {} 
B(const B &src) : a(src.a) {}
```

Beside the copy constructor I am also proposing two additional constructors, one that can be initialized by l-value instances of A and other for r-value instances. Depending on the semantics of A you may not need the move version.

Comment: I'd skip the move part and only put it in there if it really improves performance. Otherwise it just complicates the code. And your last line should not compile as a does not have a constructor that takes a B as argument.

Comment: @TobiasLangner fixed the issue. Thanks. 
Regarding the r-value overload, for the reason you mention, I have added a disclaimer. But from my previous experience in dealing with classes that looked like the one OP has, r-value overload was eventually required.

Comment: the copy constructor of B should not be necessary since the default constructed one should be sufficient in this case. This reduces the sources for error in case of refactoring.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Just another question I forgot. What would be the constructor `A(const A& obj)`?

Comment: @nullgeppetto: simply remove it. It's not necessary. The default generated one is sufficient. As a rule of thumb - as long as you don't have any manually managed resources or move-only types (like unique_ptr), the default one does the trick. Less code to maintain - fewer sources of errors.

Comment: @TobiasLangner, thanks for your help. My issue is that in B there are also other variables that need to be initialized. This happens in other code blocks. So my problem is how to initialize A a with another object of type A. So, what would be the most minimalistic solution in my problem?

Comment: @nullgeppetto as bashrc showed above. In the constructor with a parameter for A (e.g. `const A& paramA`).

Comment: I get them, but something's going really bad here... I'm trying to figure it out. Thanks all for your answers!

Comment: Thanks again everyone! Problem solved. @bashrc gave the correct solution. The conversation was also very helpful!

Answer (score 0):

```
Class A{
      public:
          A();
          A(const A& obj);
      private:
          int k;
};

Class B{
      public:
          B();
          B(const B& obj)
             : a(obj.a) { }
          B(const A& obj)
             : a(obj) { }
      private:
          A a;
};
```